# Determining SYLK error record number

Tags: microsoft-excel, sylk

I'm writing some code to build SYLK files and occasionally I'm getting an error message from Excel "Cannot read record X" where X is some mysterious number. I've tried counting records in a few different ways and can't get it to line up with anything that could be causing an error.

So, how I can correlate that record number to something in my source file?

[image: a screenshot of the error message]